# What is the term used to define an answer which does not offend anyone?

Tags: meaning-in-context

For instance - I do not want to take anyone's side in a debate and when asked about my point of view, I end up giving a smart answer which does not offend anyone of them.
What is the word for that kind of answer?

Comment: Do you want this to be a positive or negative term?  I.e., the answer to your question might be either, "a politically correct answer" or "a wishy-washy, namby-pamby, non-answer"

Comment: Seeking not to offend is good. Seeking to be honest is good. Balancing these good intentions is not always easy but will only be more difficult if you are trying to impress (whom?) by being "smart". A "noncommital" answer that is characterized by tolerance is a safe choice.

Comment: Don't forget you're also placating people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call it **diplomatic**

> Diplomatic: Of or concerning diplomacy:
>
> Diplomacy: The art of dealing with people in a sensitive and tactful
> way

(Definitions from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/ and not the only definitions of those words)

Comment: That's what I was preparing to post.  Good answer.  +1

Comment: This answer is a duplicate.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth At the time of posting a didn't see any other mentioning it. i.e. I think Josh61's only mentioned "a neutral answer". I couldn't swear to that though.

Comment: Take it and run, Avon!

Comment: But Josh61's would show an edit link if it had been so I suppose it did always include it.

Comment: It was unintentional ... it happens ... great minds, wot?

Comment: @Little Eva It was .. so it seems ...  I wouldn't know

Comment: I've often seen the variant 'politically correct' in multiple languages. It has basically the same meaning and underlying idea.

Comment: @Mast Michael Durrant gave that answer below. There are quite a lot of answers here now. I'm not surprised Megha Modi ticked the wrong one as answered (I mean mine which is ticked as the answer at the time of writing and shouldn't be because it turns out Josh61 had already said it)

Comment: Diplomatic is good. How about agnostic? Or ecumenical?

Answer (score 4):

A ***[neutral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Neutral) answer*** is generally given not to take sides with any of the party involved:

> - belonging to neither side in a controversy: on neutral ground.
> - belonging to neither kind; not one thing or the other.

The Free Dictionary

or a ***[diplomatic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diplomatic) answer*** may refer an answer which tries to avoid possible conflicts:

> - Using or marked by tact and sensitivity in dealing with others. (AHD)

Comment: Dipomatic it is .. Thanks, i was stuck on this word for an hour !

Answer (score 3):

A answer that is **politically correct** usually implies it won't offend most people.  It does *not* imply anything abut politics.

Comment: Political correctness is itself a political position,  which may please or offend the audience.

Answer (score 3):

A phrase that has been poured over so all improper implications, offensive ideas, implications of blame, and challenging statements have been removed has been **sanitized**.

Comment: You nailed it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Diplomatic would be a suitable word.

Another appropriate term would be ***[tactful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactful)***.

> careful not to offend or upset other people : having or showing tact

[mirriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactful)

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of **anodyne** in the sense of "inoffensive", but it has the implication of being dull.

Answer (score 0):

Diplomatic would fit the bill (as answered above).  But I'd say, in a following discussion of your response at the bar among your critics, the word "equivocate" would arise.

Answer (score 0):

the word innocuous means not harmful or offensive